Windows 10 PC, connected to internet using Ethernet AND Wifi?
What happens when my Windows 10 pc is connected to the internet using ethernet AND wifi at the same time? ...will that make my connection more stable?
(the reason i am asking is because: when i connect using just ethernet, the connection sometimes drops. when i connect with just wifi, the connection also sometimes drops. so i thought that if i connect ethernet AND wifi simulataneously, then when either connection temporarily losses signal then the alternate connection will take over.)
the setup;
On the first floor of the house, we have fiber modem connected to router.... on the second floor, we have just a wifi extender that is wirelessly connected to the router on the first floor.... my PC is connected to the extender using ethernet..however, the signal sometimes drops for 5 seconds.. so i connected it to the extender using wifi.. but again, the signal sometimes drops...  i then connected the pc on the second floor to the router on the  first floor (wirelessly) .. the connection seems stable but it is 50% slower then when the pc is connected to the extender on the second floor.

Is either unstable? Usually, the OS would just pick the fastest connection, likely Ethernet, for all traffic, though if Ethernet were unplugged, the OS should seamlessly switch over to WiFi.

@DrMoishePippik well yes, whichever connection i choose, they both occasionally drop signal. so i was hoping to prevent that by keeping both connections simultaneously.

If Ethernet is unstable, then likely your router or ISP has an issue which would not be helped  by adding WiFi. However, doing so would cause no harm, so you might as well test it.

@John  .. well, each one drops connection from time to time, so i though that connecting both at the same time to my pc would make the pc switch , say, from ethernet to wifi when the ethernet drops.. or switch from wifi to ethernet when the wifi drops.. ya know what imean?

If the water is shut to your house at the street, neither kitchen nor bathroom get water. If the ISP or router drops a connection, neither WiFi nor Ethernet work.

Its slightly complicated - on windows unless an application is bound to a specific interface or IP, you'll always use the interface with the best or lowest metric that's up.
I don't think that windows differentiates between 10gig or 2.5 gig but where say you have a multigig ethernet, gigabit ethernet and wifi, windows will always prefer a route that goes through the multi gig interface, the gigabit interface then wifi.
Practically on a single subnet on both it should work, and failover but  ethernet itself ought to be very much more reliabl than wireless. That you're relying on wireless and that connection being unreliable is the real issue.
Your wireless network's the weakest link, and using an extender probably isn't that helpful.
You might want to do a site survey and better position the extender or pull a cable.
I also suspect if you can't do either, this might be one of those situations where wireless mesh might be a good option, but you'd still need to consider the positions of your satillite nodes
